# Crystal Reports only printing one page with data  C# VIsual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C#. I have the following code to print a crystal report-

```
crtDiaryLabel.RecordSelectionFormula = "{PANEL_RESULT.PANEL_NUM} = " + lPanelStudyNum + " AND {PANEL_RESULT.PANEL_LEG} ='" + tPanelLeg + "' AND {PANEL_RESULT.GENERIC_PANELIST_NUM} = " + iGenPanelistNum + " AND {PANEL_RESULT.USE_NUM} <> {PANEL_RESULT.BKUP_NUM}";    
 foreach (Table tblTable in crtDiaryLabel.Database.Tables)
    {
         tiInfo = tblTable.LogOnInfo;
         tiInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciConnection;
         tblTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(tiInfo);
    }
 crtDiaryLabel.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

It will print all the records I select but only the first record will have any of the data that is set in the RecordSelectionFormula. There is also a barcode on this report and that as well only prints out for the first record. The second record and on only contains the labels with no actually data.

I have tried to print out of order and that has no effect, no matter which record I pick first or second, only the first one that prints will have any data.

Any idea on why this would happen and how to fix it?

Thanks.